# istio - whitelist particular ip/range for a virtualservice endpoint

Tags: istio

With istio is it possible to whitelist particular ip/range for a virtualservice endpoint.
The use case I have endpoint that I want to expose through internal loadbalancer but only available for particular CI/CD component like Jenkins.